# Unitary freedom of Cholesky Factorization of PSD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am looking for a proof or reference for the statement: if $Q$ is positive semidefinite, then it has a Cholesky factorization
$$Q=q q^t$$
and **$q$ is unique up to a unitary transformation**.

Comment: There is actually a difficulty here, in that the Cholesky decomposition $A = LL^T$ with lower triangular matrix $L$ need not exist for positive *semidefinite* $A$.  Suppose for example that first row and column entry $A_{1,1}=0$.

Comment: That's a fair point - I think now that my question is misleading. I allow q to be rectangular. I also found a reference with the statement I was looking for: "Semidefinite optimization and convex algebraic geometry"

Comment: Wikipedia gives [a nonconstructive argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Proof_for_positive_semi-definite_matrices) for the positive semi-definite cases, by existence of factors in a convergent subsequence of the factorizations of positive definite "perturbations" $Q + (1/k)I$.